# Angular velocity in Fick Spherical coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates

On wikipedia and mathworld it is explained how angular velocity is calculated in spherical coordinates. The coordinate system used there is however not what I am using. In my field, coordinates follow the Fick gimbal. The transforms for this system are:
$$\begin{align}
x &= \rho\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}\\
y &= \rho\sin{\phi}\\
z &= \rho\cos{\phi}\cos{\theta}
\end{align}$$
and the inverses:
$$\begin{align}
\rho &= \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\
\theta &= \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{z}\\
\phi &= \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\\
\end{align}$$

That is, $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle/rotation in the $x$-$z$ plane, and $\phi$ the elevation/rotation out of the $x$-$z$ plane.

Now, i would like to determine the expression for angular velocity of a point in this coordinate system. I know from secondary sources that the answer is 
$$
v=\sqrt{\dot\theta^2\cos^2\phi+\phi^2}
$$
but i have trouble arriving at it. I have done the following:

I found the following [two](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4892&view=html) [texts](https://www.cpp.edu/~ajm/materials/delsph.pdf), which explain how to determine the angular derivatives based on the unit vectors of the spherical system, and [this answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70540/117610) for how to derive the unit vectors.

Following the steps of the latter link to find $\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}$, $\boldsymbol{\hat\theta}$, and $\boldsymbol{\hat{\phi}}$, we take the derivative of the spherical coordinate representation $(\rho\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}, \rho\sin{\phi}, \rho\cos{\phi}\cos{\theta})$ with respect to $\rho$, $\theta$, and $\phi$, respectively, and then normalize each one. This yields:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{\hat\rho} \\ \boldsymbol{\hat\theta}  \\ \boldsymbol{\hat\phi} \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\phi\sin\theta & \sin\phi & \cos\phi\cos\theta \\                    \cos\phi\cos\theta & 0 & -\cos\phi\sin\theta \\  -\sin\phi\sin\theta & \cos\phi & -\cos\theta\sin\phi \end{bmatrix}    \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{\hat x} \\ \mathbf{\hat y} \\ \mathbf{\hat z} \end{bmatrix}$$
If i understand correctly, each row is a unit vector here.

Then, following [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4892&view=html),
$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{v}&=\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{\rho}\\
&=\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}\cdot\frac{d\rho}{dt}+\rho\cdot\frac{d\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{dt}\\
&=\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}\cdot\frac{d\rho}{dt}+\rho\cdot\biggl(\frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{\delta \rho}\cdot\frac{d\rho}{dt}+\frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{\delta \theta}\cdot\frac{d\theta}{dt}+\frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{\delta \phi}\cdot\frac{d\phi}{dt}\biggr)
\end{align}
$$

To solve that equation, we need the partial derivatives of $\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}$ with respect to $\rho$, $\theta$, and $\phi$, which are:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{\delta\rho} &= 0\\
\frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{\delta\theta} &= \cos\phi\cos\theta - \cos\phi\sin\theta\\
 &= \boldsymbol{\hat\theta}\\
\frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{\delta\phi} &= - \sin\phi\sin\theta + \cos\phi - \cos\theta\sin\phi \\
 &= \boldsymbol{\hat\phi}
\end{align}
$$

which would make:
$$
\boldsymbol{v}=\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\cdot\frac{d\rho}{dt}+\rho\cdot\biggl(\boldsymbol{\hat\theta}\cdot\frac{d\theta}{dt}+\boldsymbol{\hat\phi}\cdot\frac{d\phi}{dt}\biggr)
$$
 and thereby
$$
v=\sqrt{\dot\theta^2+\dot\phi^2},
$$
which isn't right!

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the vector summation in the calculation below

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{\delta\rho} &= 0\\
\frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{\delta\theta} &= \sqrt{(\cos\phi\cos\theta)^2+( - \cos\phi\sin\theta)^2}\boldsymbol{\hat\theta} \\
 &= \cos\phi\boldsymbol{\hat\theta}\\
\frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\hat\rho}}{\delta\phi} &= \sqrt{(- \sin\phi\sin\theta)^2 + \cos^2\phi +(- \cos\theta\sin\phi)^2 }\boldsymbol{\hat\phi}\\
 &= \boldsymbol{\hat\phi}
\end{align}
$$

Then, you will get

$$
v=\sqrt{\dot\theta^2\cos^2\phi+\dot\phi^2},
$$

Comment: Hmm, that does the trick. But, why? Are you able to elucidate on/point me to the step i missed? It seems quite different from the two documents i linked to my (admittedly) untrained eye

Comment: Ha, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) to the rescue. I see that to calculate the coefficients for determining how $\hat\rho$ changes with each of the spherical coordinates, we need to take the vector magnitude of the partial diffs. Thanks!

Comment: Correct, which is why you need to take the vector sum at the end.