# Conversion of a vector field from Cartesian to Polar Co-Ordinate Systems

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, classical-mechanics

I understand that textbook questions are to be avoided here but I would like to request help from this forum. This a question in mechanics which involves what should be a fairly straightforward conversion between Cartesian and polar co-ordinate systems. But this question has left me and my classmates stumped because the answer obtained from conversion is nowhere near the required solution. Here is the question:

> Show that the equations
>   $$E_r = \frac{p}{2\pi\epsilon_0r^3}\cos\theta \qquad E_\theta=\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}\sin\theta$$
>   follow from
>   $$E_x=\frac{3p\sin\theta\cos\theta}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}\qquad
> E_z= \frac{p(3\cos^2\theta-1)}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}$$

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUVuO.jpg))

$E_x$, $E_z$, $E_r$, $E_\theta$ represent the electric field vector along the $x$-axis, $z$-axis, $r$-component and $\theta$-component. So, my question is whether this proof  is possible or is there a minor error which when corrected gives the required answer?

Edit: Here's my attempt at the proof:

Assumptions:

**(a)** $$E_r = \sqrt {E_x^2+E_z^2}$$

**(b)** $$E_\theta = \tan^{-1} (E_z/ E_x)$$

**(c)** $$k = \frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}$$

Then we obtain,

$$E_r = 2k\cos\theta$$ $$E_\theta = k\sin\theta$$ $$E_x = 3k\sin\theta\cos\theta$$ $$E_z = k(3\cos^2\theta -1)$$

Plugging these values into **(a)** and simplifying, I obtained:
$$E_r = k\sqrt {3\cos^2\theta +1}$$
after which I was stuck.

Plugging the values into **(b)** and simplifying, I obtained:
$$E_\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac {3\cos^2\theta-1}{3\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$

I attempted to simplify this by separating one $cos^2\theta$ terma so I could have two cosine terms in my numerator:
$$E_\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac {\cos^2\theta+\cos2\theta}{3\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$
I separated them and multiplied the second term by $\frac 22$ so I could convert both of them into tangent terms:
$$E_\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac {\cos^2\theta}{3\sin\theta\cos\theta}+ \frac {\cos2\theta}{3\sin\theta\cos\theta}*\frac 22$$
$$E_\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac {1}{3\tan\theta}+ \frac {1}{3\tan2\theta}$$
All attempts after this were in vain.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... You should definitely post your own attempt at the proof. The more you can tell us about what you know (or don't know) about a problem, the better. This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Comment: In addition to @Blue's comment, I think you should also try to make the title more informative, so that people knows what the question is about. "Need help with" is not necessary (why would you be asking if you didn't need it?) and "trigonometry" is soooo general... What about something like "Conversion between Cartesian and polar coordinate systems"? Welcome :)

Comment: @Blue Thank you! Will do.

Comment: @AugSB Thanks. Done!

Answer (score 1):

Probably either the problem is wrongly stated or wrong understood. In any case the statement is ambiguous as the vector components in an allegedly Cartesian coordinate system are given using polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.

Recognizing that the transformed value is a vector the transformation can be obtained using:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E_r\\
E_\theta
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
E_x\\
E_z
\end{pmatrix}=-\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}
\begin{pmatrix}
2\sin\theta\\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Compared to the required result we have obtained the opposite sign and interchanged trigonometric functions. Still, I would not claim that the result is "nowhere near" the required solution. One can even enforce the desired solution by the convention that the angle $\theta$ is measured in clockwise direction from the $z$-axis. And it is very probable that exactly this convention was (probably unintentionally) used by the authors of the exercise as the example obviously originates from the dipole field presented in *cylindrical coordinate system* with dipole moment directed along $z$-axis.

Comment: Could you explain that a little more? I don't quite get what you've done here.

Comment: I would suggest you to start with reading this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70493 .

Comment: So what you've done here is represent the vectors in a matrix form and multiplied the matrices? Then I guess you're comparing the top and bottom rows of both the matrices to obtain $E_r$ and $E_\theta$?

Comment: @ThisSentientNeuron Yes, this is exactly what is done here.

Comment: I tried and failed. Did my best. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @ThisSentientNeuront What did you try and where did you fail?

Comment: It's alright. I finally found a different way to solve it.

Comment: That's nice. You can publish it as your own answer.